# How can I stop a CruiseControl build or change the configuration to cause long running builds to time out?

Tags: java, ant, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

Is there any way to stop an active CruiseControl build short of stopping and restarting CruiseControl? I'm running [CruiseControl Dashboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl#Dashboard) version 2.7.2.

If there is no way to stop an active build, or how can I cause long running builds to timeout? Is this something I should configure in CruiseControl or in Ant?

### Background

It looks like a networking change is causing some of our test cases to wait for a long time before timing out. This is causing the CruiseControl build to take a REALLY long time to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the [ant task](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#ant) (and most other build tasks too) by setting the optional timeout property in the configuration.

> Ant build will be halted if it continues longer than the specified timeout. Value in seconds.

The example below will halt the build after 60 seconds:

```
<schedule>
  <ant antscript="C:\Java\apache-ant-1.6.1\bin\ant.bat"
     antworkingdir="D:\workspace\MyProject"
     buildfile="MyProject-nightlybuild.xml"
     timeout="60"/>
<schedule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pause, resume, force-start and otherwise manage a CruiseControl build by using [JMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) server. For more information, see *[Managing CruiseControl With JMX](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/Managing+CruiseControl+With+JMX)*.